# When can limit of a sequence of characteristic be also a characteristic function?

Tags: characteristic-functions, sequence-of-function

Say {$\phi_n$} be a sequence of characteristic function with some densities {$f_n$} that converges pointwise to $\phi$ , i.e., $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi_n (t) = \phi(t) \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$ . If $\phi$ is continuous at 0 , how to show $\phi$ is a characteristic function ?

Is it like $\phi$ satisfies basic properties like it is continuous , $\phi(0)=1$ ,$|\phi|\le1$ , so $\phi$ is a characteristic function ? But if that is the case why these basic properties implies $\phi$ being a characteristic function ?

Comment: This is the Lévy continuity theorem. Any good probability theory text has a proof (I can recommend Durrett). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X_{n}\xrightarrow{d} X\iff \phi_{X_{n}}(t)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\phi_{X}(t)$ .

So now suppose you construct $X_{1},X_{2},..$ such that they have their cf as $\phi_{X_{n}}$.

It can be shown that this sequence of rv's is a tight sequence.

Then using Tightness you get a subsequence and a random variable $X$ such that $X_{n_{k}}\xrightarrow{d} X$.

So $\phi=\phi_{X}$ ( using pointwise convergence).

Which in particular implies that $\phi$ is a cf as it agrees with $\phi_{X}$ which is a cf .

For the proof of Tightness you can refer to Rick Durrett as suggested in the comments on page 132-133. [Here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) is a link for the pdf